# program closes prematurly with pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

iv'e been trying to make a personnel assistant and i have been using pttsx3 with tkinter to talk to you but when i run the code it closes the programm immediately and i am wandering how to keep it open so i can ask multiple questions
so i guess i am asking how to keep the mainloop() open fir tkinter after pyttsx3 runs

heres what the actuall voice part looks like but this closes immediately

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("This is Text-To-Speech Engine Pyttsx3")
engine.runAndWait()
engine.stop()
```

this dose not include the tkinter part of my code
i have searched for something to try but have found no one with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to you not having tts drivers on your PC. The [SAPI5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121) for windows XP-10
[NSSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer) for MACOS Leopard and Snow Leopard and [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) for Ubuntu.

Comment: to clarify it dose run and it dose speak but then imidietly kills the programm